# Fill columns with most recent value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset like this in R:

```
Date       | ID  | Age |
2019-11-22 | 1   | 5   |
2018-12-21 | 1   | 4   |
2018-05-09 | 1   | 4   |
2018-05-01 | 2   | 5   |
2017-10-10 | 2   | 4   |
2017-07-21 | 1   | 3   |
```

How do I change the Age values of each group of ID to the most recent Age record?

Results should look like this:

```
Date       | ID  | Age |
2019-11-22 | 1   | 5   |
2018-12-21 | 1   | 5   |
2018-05-09 | 1   | 5   |
2018-05-01 | 2   | 5   |
2017-10-10 | 2   | 5   |
2017-07-21 | 1   | 5   |
```

I tried `group_by(ID)%>% mutate(Age = max(Date, Age))`
but it seems to be giving strange huge numbers for certain cases when I try it on a v huge dataset. What could be going wrong?

Comment: just order on your date and replace all values with the first (or last depending how you will sort). Also the most recent for group 2 is 5...

Comment: why is Age `4` for ID `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sorting first,

```
df %>% 
 arrange(as.Date(Date)) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(Age = last(Age))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>   Date          ID   Age
>   <fct>      <int> <int>
> 1 2017-07-21     1     5
> 2 2017-10-10     2     5
> 3 2018-05-01     2     5
> 4 2018-05-09     1     5
> 5 2018-12-21     1     5
> 6 2019-11-22     1     5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your mutate function:

Try this:

```
    group_by(ID) %>% 
arrange(as.date(Date) %>%
mutate(Age = max(Age))
```

Comment: This does not take most recent Date into account.